# I need to know if this always true or if there is some case this becomes false $E[f(X, Y )|Y = y] = E[f(X, y)]$

Tags: probability-distributions, conditional-expectation

The statement is as the title states:

> Will the following expression always be true or is there some scenarios where it might be false?
> $$E[g(X, Y)|Y = y] = E[g(X,y)].$$

Comment: If $X = u(Y),$ and $Y$ is known, then $X$ is also known.

Comment: it's true whenever $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please tell us what have you tried to this problem. It will help us to answer what exactly you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

In general it holds that
$$\mathbb{E}[g(X,Y) \: | \: Y=y] = \mathbb{E}[g(X,y) \: | \: Y=y].$$
If we can assume that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then it also holds that
$$\mathbb{E}[g(X,y) \: | \: Y=y] = \mathbb{E}[g(X,y)].$$

Comment: Ahh I see, only if they are independent can I remove the condition from the right side. thanks a lot !